# Is there a possible way to parse this address

Tags: node.js

What's tha best way to parse addresses like these with Node:

```
Address: 'Yaseen Burlingame Center, 1722 Gilbreth Rd, Burlingame, CA 94010, USA'
Address: 'Hub 925, 5341 Owens Ct, Pleasanton, CA 94588, USA'
Address: 'Young Ave Parking, Young Ave, Half Moon Bay, CA 94019, USA'
```

Comment: split on commas

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything more about exactly what you need to parse out the string, and based purely on the format of it, [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) would be a good place to start.

```
const parts = address.split(',');
parts[0] // Yaseen Burlingame Center
parts[1] // 1722 Gilbreth Rd
...
```

*Note - you would have some extra whitespace in each part that you can remove via [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)*